# Can someone provide a map of Nazca lines with this image in it?

Tags: earth-history, earth-observation

I found this image of a bird with another image below its right wing on google earth in nazca peru. Is there any maps or infomation available that can help me identify this one?[image]

Kind regards
Jeff B.

Answer (score 1):

[go2peru](http://www.go2peru.com/peru_guide/nazca/map_nazca_lines.htm)  has a nice set of maps of the Nazca area.